# Pepper: display temporal image

Tags: python-2.7, pepper, choregraphe

In my Choregraphe project, the robot calls an API to retrieve images (encoded in base64) that it will shows in its tablet.

So the robot calls the API, get the JSON of data and save it inside a file. After, it opens the file, read the image and decode it. the decoded image is saved as a temporal file and at the end, it calls this temporal image to show on tablet using `tabletService.showImage(url)`

The problem I have is that the robot doesn't show any image and does not throw any error or exception. I don't know how to solve it.

```
def onInput_onStart(self):
    # We create TabletService here in order to avoid
    # problems with connections and disconnections of the tablet during the life of the application
    import json
    import base64
    import tempfile

    tabletService = self._getTabletService()
    if tabletService:
        try:
            senaleticas = ''
            with open('senaleticas.json', 'r') as fr:
                strSenaleticas = fr.read()

            senaleticas = json.loads(strSenaleticas)

            image64 = senaleticas[0]['_mapa']
            image = base64.b64decode(image64)

            f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
            f.write(image)

            url = self._getAbsoluteUrl(f.name)

            self.logger.info("-> " + url)

            tabletService.showImage(url)
        except Exception as err:
            self.logger.error("Error during ShowImage : %s " % err)
            self.onStopped()
    else:
        self.logger.warning("No ALTabletService, can't display the image.")
        self.onStopped()
```

The log shows that the var `log` has the value  `http://198.18.0.1/apps/.lastUploadedChoregrapheBehavior/tmp/tmpEhJeOS`

[image]

**Note:** if there is another way to show images, I'm interested in it.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try with the correct file extension to the image, for example *png*:

```
f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.png')
```

Comment: That doesn't work. At the moment I have implemented a temporal solution that is displaying the image in an HTML file via JS. 
With the image box the tablet doesn't do anything that seems loading an image

Comment: You write 'temporal', do you mean 'temporary'?

Comment: I would like to know if the 'Show Image'-box is able to work at all.
Please try this: Create a folder named 'html' and put it in the project root folder (same level as the .pml file). Then insert an image file in the 'html' folder. Then use the 'Show Image' box. In the box parameters set the string 'ImageURL' to the image name. For example 'cat.jpg'. Do not include the path name. The box is hard-coded to use the 'html' folder.

Comment: Have images to be inside the **html** folder or can be in any folder inside the project?

Comment: They must be in the html folder. The nginx server is configured that way.

Comment: The temporally images are  created automatically under the `/temp` folder. I tried to use `f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir='html')` but it throws `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'html/tmpCJ33jY'`. I putted an image directly in html folder and it works. I think that I will use the HTML solution that I have done this morning.